# Connecting one network with other using router

Tags: networking

Dears,
I have devices in location-1 with IP addresses 172.16.X.Y and subnet mask 255.240.0.0. I have server in location-2 with IP address 172.23.21.1 and subnet mask 255.240.0.0

I am using a Fortinet firewall between these 2 locations (Location-1 & 2). I want to receive data from all devices in location-1 at location-2 Server. Please guide how and what default gateway I can use in each device of location-1 to achieve this target

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: With your netmask, both network segments can be unified into one, depending on the architecture. We need a diagram of your two networks, including connections, routers and firewall.

Comment: If location 2 is remote from location 1 set up a VPN between the two.